# Jquery Dialog with ASP.net postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, iframe, postback

I like to have a dialog modal with external url link, and inside the dialog is allowed to save without closing the dialog. I not sure this is the best way to do it but at least when button save the dialog modal not close. So in order for me to click save button in the modal popup without closing the dialog, i use together with Iframe, but there are 2 problems:

1. the css is different if run without `//dialog.load(url);`
2. the iframe can't auto resize.

So anyone got solution for this?

```
$('.popupEdit').click(function () {
    var url = this.href;


    var dialog = $('<div id="pEdit"><iframe id="iframedit" src="' + url + '" style="width:1200px;height:490px;"  frameborder="0" ></iframe></div>').appendTo('body');
    //var dialog = $('<iframe src="' + url + '" style="width:1200px;height:490px;"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
    //dialog.load(url);
    dialog.dialog({
        autoResize: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        draggable: true,
        open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); },
        close: function (type, data) { $("[id$=btnSearch]").click(); }
   });
```

Comment: I do not see a "save" button and the iframe does not seem like the proper solution given your description and the code that does not match that description.

Comment: Sorry for the title. the save button is in the external link.

Answer (score 0):

May be this alternative can provide you with the requirement:

You can use TinyBox popup at http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/
with `Iframe` Option.

has same features as you mentioned have mentioned...

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's almost same like what i've. May be i could customize the css as this look more simple to change than the jquery library. :)